# How to direct trial output to files

Tags: ray

I'm running an `Experiment` with multiple trials and I would like to log the STDOUT for the process for each trial in a file in the directory created in `ray_results` for that trial.

I have set `log_to_driver` [to false](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/worker.py#L1221) since the driver couldn't keep up and I have set `redirect_worker_output` [to true](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/worker.py#L1225) but that doesn't seem to result in what I want either.

Perhaps there is [an option in](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/tune.py#L156) `ray.tune.run`? I have set `verbose=2` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Would it be possible to simply set `sys.stdout` to an open file?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I just thought that `redirect_worker_output` [would do that](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/c2349cf12daac0b831f54d6baa2117d9f6923655/python/ray/parameter.py#L41). What is the intended purpose of that argument?

Comment: Is it possible to get the directory of the current trial from the `reporter`?

Comment: redirect_worker_output is deprecated; but I also think the logging mechanisms need to be improved (but this is a ray core issue). You can get `os.getcwd` to access the directory.

Comment: oh that's interesting I didn't know `ray` used the trial directory as the working directory for the newly created trial processes

Comment: yeah, we'll fix the docs so that it's clearer